# Repairing broken file associations on the Mac

Tags: safari, google-chrome

I installed a download manager (I think folx) on this mac book a few months ago, every time I would download a file folx would pick up and download it.

Long story short, this got confusing, so I deleted folx from the applications.

Now whenever I try to download a file it just does not work right (on either chrome or safari), the browsers complain about a broken plugin when I view a PDF and it seems safari attempts to download the file on the actual page as opposed to going to the download queue.

How do I fix this so file downloads work again in the browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Folx does a fair bit of damage on a simple delete uninstall.

Instead, re-download folx and run the uninstaller app.

See: http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/downloader-macos/uninstall.html